# Term for "brain-watering"

Tags: word-choice, expressions, adjectives, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

A mouth can water, but what does a brain do? I'm looking for a term that implies intellectual thirst, as when one has worked all day at a mindless task and only wants to read a novel, or essay, or weighty film.

**Update**
On further reflection, I realized that what I'm actually trying to find a term for is the sensation one gets when hearing that a favorite author is about to publish a new book, or when one sees a captivating title in a list of movies. The mouth "waters" when we're hungry and smell good food. But what does the mind do when we walk into a bookstore or art gallery?

Answer (score 5):

Generally the mind hungers rather than thirsts.  Feed your brain, don't water it!

For a general phrase, I would use "intellectually starved for a good book" or something similar.  This is usage number three from http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/starved

Comment: Thanks for the thought! I agree with your proposition. Thinking about it more, however, I realized that I'm actually after something a little different (I've edited the post accordingly). My fault, of course, not yours.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all something very close to the OP :-)

> Reading Christopher Smart in the Twenty-first Century: "By ... - Page
>   xii Min Wild, ‎Noel Chevalier - 2013 -
>
> acknowledgments are to Rosa Duvet, of course, as well as to, once
>   again, Professor Dafydd Moore, and, as always, **for keeping the brain
>   watered,** to Drs. Michael Nath, Paul Hendon, and Laura Salisbury.

>

> Dead Woman Pickney: A Memoir of Childhood in Jamaica
>
> Yvonne Shorter Brown - 2010
>
> My **brain was
>   ravenous for** knowledge, and my soulwas hungry for adventure—to study,
>   to travel, to work abroad, and totravel around the world.

>

> Clonenstein: The Sixth Great-Grandson of Frankenstein - Page 5 Gary B.
>   Cooke - 2010
>
> My **brain was hungry for** knowledge. I was like a sponge; I needed to
>   know more and more.

Comment: Thanks. These make a good case. I changed my post, however, realizing in hindsight that I'm looking more for a verb than an adjective. These quotes may still apply; the brain may "hunger" when hearing about a new book. But I wonder if there's something closer to "intellectual salivating" (an admittedly awkward phrase).